# Mac Automator (OS 10.7) not reading Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby-1.9.3, automator

I have some Ruby code in a .rb file that I am trying to run with Automator as opposed to the Command Line. Here is a sample of the code (filename is "filelines_revise.rb"):

```
lines = IO.readlines('filelines_before_CAP.txt').map do |line|

  array = line.split.each { |i| i.capitalize! }

  if array.include?("Ws")
    array.delete("Ws")
    array[-1,0] = "Ws"
  end

  if array.include?("Es")
    array.delete("Es")
    array[-1,0] = "Es"
  end

  array_2 = array.join(" ")

  array_2.gsub(/ Ws /, ", west side")
         .gsub(/ ES /, ", east side")
end

File.open('filelines_after_CAP.txt', 'w') do |file|
  file.puts lines
end
```

When I run this code using the command line command "ruby /Desktop/filelines_revise/filelines_revise.rb" and the code runs fine. It finds the original .txt file, reads each line, changes the file as the code dictates, then creates a new file with the revised lines.

When I try to put this into Automator as either a Workflow or an App, I put Run Shell Script to my flow, using /bin/bash with a Pass input: to stdin, then the command "ruby /Desktop/filelines_revise/filelines_revise.rb". When I go to run the script I get an error reading:

Desktop/filelines_revise/filelines_revise.rb:18 syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting Kend

Line 18 is the 2nd .gsub ".gsub(/ ES /, ", east side")" listed in the code above.

Is it possible Automator isn't using my Ruby 1.9.3 as the Command Line does? Perhaps I should be going about this differently? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Line 18 is the 2nd .gsub `.gsub(/ ES /, ", east side")` listed in the code above" Yes, and if you close that up (put it on the same line with the first gsub) does that fix it?

Comment: @matt it fixes it when I run a Service, but not an app. Once I did, it told me it could not find the file. I am going with a Service, though will leave open as I would rather have an App one day.

Answer (score 0):

How is your Ruby version determined? I'm betting that Automator knows nothing of it. It is probably running the built-in Ruby 1.8.7. You can easily check that by examining `RUBY_VERSION` in the course of your script.

The issue would then be that the shell environment for double-clickables (like Automator) is not the same as the shell environment for the Terminal (which uses your `.bash_profile`).

BBEdit had the same problem until version 10.5, by the way. It takes a special effort for a double-clickable app to pick up the Terminal shell environment, and most applications do not make that effort.

EDIT: I took a look at Automator and discovered that if you run a shell script that you enter literally with the Run Shell Script action, you have to switch the popup to `/usr/bin/ruby`. But of course my ruby is *not* the ruby at `/usr/bin/ruby`. `/usr/bin/ruby` is 1.8.7; that is the ruby I do *not* want to use. And you can't provide a shebang line!

So I set the popup to `/bin/bash/` and ran this script:

```
/usr/bin/env ruby /Users/matt/Desktop/test.rb
```

Where `test.rb` reads:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
```

Running that within Automator, I still got "1.8.7". I also tried it as an application and as a service; same result. So I don't think you can ever get Automator to use anything but the built-in ruby 1.8.7 without pointing directly to the ruby that you want; it doesn't pick it up from the shell the way Terminal does.

Comment: I don't know how to tell which version Automator defaults to. In command line, it says 1.9.3. I still haven't figured out how to make a double-clickable app, however I did get it to work with a Service, which will suit my needs for now. I will leave this question open as I think it is still valuable and would rather have an app than a service.

Comment: As I said, consult `RUBY_VERSION` from within your script to learn which version of ruby you are running under.

Comment: @jmitchell1009 To extend @matt excellent answer, it looks like what you're trying to do is specific, so the code doesn't need to be portable. If that is the case, you can hardcode the full path to the version of ruby you want. To see where that is, you can run `which ruby` in a terminal window. Once you have the path, you can specify it in your script like `path/to/ruby path/to/script`.