# macOS Automator's Ruby defaults to ASCII despite being >= 1.9

Tags: ruby, macos, encoding, utf-8, automator

I am trying to get access to the text in the macOS clipboard from within Automator using a Ruby script. This script calls macOS's internal Ruby (/usr/bin/ruby). After running into much trouble with unidentified character sequence errors, I noticed that Automator's Ruby defaults to ASCII instead of UTF-8, while this is not the default behaviour of modern Ruby since years ago.

So, running the following:

```
require 'clipboard'    
puts(Clipboard.paste.encoding)
```

*always* yields "ASCII", while running the same Ruby interpreter from the command line to run the same script and to paste the same pieces of text *always* yields "UTF-8".

This becomes an issue when I copy multibyte characters like the accented characters (e.g. ê). For instance if I copy the following text:

> Bourdieu, P., & Passeron, J.-C. (1970). La reproduction: éléments pour une théorie du système d’enseignement. Ed. de Minuit.

And then run:

```
require 'clipboard'    
puts(Clipboard.paste)
```

I get nothing in Automator while I get a copy of the original text on the command line.

If I try to transform the text in any way, I get an error. Let's say I run the following:

```
require 'clipboard'
puts(Clipboard.paste.gsub(/\r/,""))
```

In response, I will receive:

```
-e:2:in `gsub': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
from -e:2:in `<main>'
```

How can I avoid this and make sure what I get from the clipboard is already converted into proper UTF-8?

I have tried `encode` and `force_encoding` methods, as well as a variety of combinations of `# encoding: UTF-8`, `Encoding.default_external='utf-8'` and `Encoding.default_internal='utf-8'`, but it seems there are corrupt characters that hinder the conversion, so no success in the end.

Is there anything I am ignoring here, or any combination I haven't tried?

Notes:

1. It is Automator that calls the interpreter, and not me. So, I can't modify Automator's call to add switches and modify options.
2. `string.encode!('UTF-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')` works, but the sanitization comes at the cost of chopping off the multibyte characters, which is obviously not the intended behaviour here.

Comment: What does "sporadically" mean?

Comment: @Stefan I am copying the texts from sources whose encoding is not known to me. I am not sure how to detect the encoding of the pieces of text in the clipboard. Probably one way to debug is first to see whether there are encoding differences in the original texts. That, though, doesn't change the fact that when running macOS's Ruby from the command line , I always get UTF-8.

Comment: Did you have a look here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344287/mac-automator-os-10-7-not-reading-ruby-1-9-3#16344450

Comment: Can you give an example for a source that results in ASCII encoding?

Comment: @lacostenycoder Sure! Yields "2.0.0".

Comment: @Stefan I revised the question and clarified the issue, and added an example.  I hope this helps you reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to replace binary ruby with modern one?. Also which mac os version do you run, that you have so old ruby?

Comment: @Advept I do have another version of Ruby running on my system, but Automator calls the binary version automatically. The OS version is 10.12.6 (16G29).

Answer (score 1):

I found that in macOS Mojave 10.14.6, starting the Automator 'Run Shell Script' with `# coding: UTF-8` solved the problem. Not sure the `#!/usr/bin/ruby` is useful or necessary, but I include it. You can test by using this code with and without the `# coding: UTF-8`:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# coding: UTF-8

test_s = "will print ✪"
puts test_s
```

[image]

Credit for the answer is from here: [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250240594?page=2)